# Javascript not working, possibly due to conflict

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

http://www.hcfmissoula.com/grants/compassionate-care-grant

I have this simple radio button form, and if the user answers "yes" to each question, I want a hidden link to show up at the bottom.  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input:radio').change(function(){
    if(
        ($('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group2]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group3]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &&
        ($('input:radio[name=group4]:checked').val() == 'Yes')
    ){
        document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.com/somefile.pdf">grab the file here</a></div>';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('pdflink').innerHTML = '';
    }

});
</script>

<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<div><br>
<p>Question 1?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 2?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 3?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"> No<br>
<hr>
<p>Question 4?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"> No<br>
</div>
</form>

<div id="pdflink">
</div>
```

The link is not showing up in `#pdflink` when I click all of the yes buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: Based on my answer below, here's a snippet of how you need to set up your file to make this work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        // etc.
    });
});
</script>

<form name="myform" action="" method="POST">
<!-- etc. -->
```

The code starting with `$('input:radio').change` is executed immediately, **before** the following HTML has been rendered and added to the DOM. You need to wrap that code in a `$(document).ready` call to make it execute *after* the document has loaded.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQMdA/) for evidence that, otherwise, your code works correctly. jsFiddle automatically puts the code from the JavaScript frame inside a `$(document).ready` call, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Also see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQMdA/1/) for a more consistent way to achieve the same thing (uses jQuery only, not a combination of jQuery and built-in JavaScript functions). Purely a suggestion.

Comment: So, you'll have to forgive me because I'm a noob with javascript, but where do I insert this bit of code?  I'm already calling js 1.6.2 in the header...

Comment: You want to wrap that code around the javascript in your example.  Also you should try and move all your script blocks to the bottom of your page, just before the closing </body> tag.  http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: @Dan Tao I've implemented the changes (http://www.hcfmissoula.com/grants/compassionate-care-grant), and I still can't get the link to show up.  Thanks, btw, for your patience and help.

Comment: @blackessej: I visited the link, and it looks like you *did* get it to work! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code in Chrome, I see this.  Your ampersands are getting escaped and Chrome is saying `compassionate-care-grant:197Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

```
if(
    ($('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
    ($('input:radio[name=group2]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
    ($('input:radio[name=group3]:checked').val() == 'Yes') &#038;&#038;
    ($('input:radio[name=group4]:checked').val() == 'Yes')
){
```

Comment: Side note, you need to clean up your included scripts.  I see at least three different jQuerys.